# Random Effects in Longitudinal Multilevel Imputation Models Using MICE

Tags: r, mixed-models, r-mice

I am trying to impute data in dataset with a longitudinal design. There are two predictors (experimental group, and time) and one outcome variable (score). The clustering variable is id.

Here is the toy data

```
set.seed(345)
A0 <- rnorm(4,2,.5)
B0 <- rnorm(4,2+3,.5)
A1 <- rnorm(4,6,.5)
B1 <- rnorm(4,6+2,.5)
A2 <- rnorm(4,10,.5)
B2 <- rnorm(4,10+1,.5)
A3 <- rnorm(4,14,.5)
B3 <- rnorm(4,14+0,.5)
score <- c(A0,B0,A1,B1,A2,B2,A3,B3)
id <- rep(1:8,times = 4, length = 32)
time <- rep(0:3, each = 8, length = 32)
group <- rep(c("A","B"), times =2, each = 4, length = 32)
df <- data.frame(id = id, group = group, time = time,  score = score)

# plots
(ggplot(df, aes(x = time, y = score, group = group)) + 
    stat_summary(fun.y = "mean", geom = "line", aes(linetype = group)) +
    stat_summary(fun.y = "mean", geom = "point", aes(shape = group), size = 3) +
    coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,18)))

# now place some NAs
df[sample(1:nrow(df), 10, replace = F),"score"] <- NA

df
```

If I understand [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38100892/imputation-using-mice-with-clustered-data) correctly, in the predictor matrix I should specify the `id` clustering variable with a `-2` and the two fixed predictors `time` and `group` with a `1`. Like so

```
library(mice)

(ini <- mice(df, maxit=0))
(pred <- ini$predictorMatrix)
(pred["score",] <- c(-2, 1, 1, 0))
(imp <- mice(df, 
            method = c("", "", "", "2l.pan"),
            pred = pred, 
            maxit = 1, 
            seed = 71152))
```

What i would like to know is:

1. Is this a longitudinal random intercepts imputation model? Specifying the id variable as `-2` designates it as a 'class' variable, but in [this mice primer](https://research.utwente.nl/en/publications/mice-multivariate-imputation-by-chained-equations-in-r) it suggests that for multilevel models you should create a variable of all `1`'s in the dataframe as a constant, which is then specified as the random intercept via `2` in the predictor matrix. However, this is based on the `2l.norm` function rather than the `2l.pan` function, so I am not really sure where I am here. Does the `2l.pan` function not require this column, or the specification of random effects?
2. Is there any way to specify a longitudinal random-slopes model, and, if so, how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer is probably a bit late for you, but it may be able to help some people who read this in the future:

### How to work with `2l.pan`

Below are some details about specifying multilevel imputation models with `mice`. Because the application is longitudinal, I use the term "persons" to refer to units at Level 2. These are the most relevant arguments for `2l.pan` as mentioned in the `mice` documentation:

> `type`
>
> Vector of length `ncol(x)` identifying random and class variables.
> Random effects are identified by a `2`. The group variable (only one
> is allowed) is coded as `-2`.  Random effects also include the fixed
> effect.  If for a covariates `X1` group means shall be calculated and
> included as further fixed effects choose `3`.  In addition to the
> effects in `3`, specification `4` also includes random effects of
> `X1`.

There are 5 different codes you can use in the predictor matrix for variables imputed with `2l.pan`. The person identifier is coded as `-2` (this is different from `2l.norm`). To include predictor variables with fixed or random effects, these variables are coded with `1` or `2`, respectively. If coded as `2`, the corresponding fixed effect is automatically included.

In addition, `2l.pan` offers the codes `3` and `4`, which have similar meanings as `1` and `2` but will include an additional fixed effect for the person mean of that variable. This is useful if you're trying to model within- and between-person effects of time-varying predictor variables.

> `intercept`
>
> Logical determining whether the intercept is automatically added.

By default, `2l.pan` includes the intercept as both a fixed and a random effect. For this reason, it is *not required* to include a constant term in the predictor matrix. If one sets `intercept=FALSE`, this behavior is changed, and the intercept is dropped from the imputation model.

> `groupcenter.slope`
>
> If `TRUE`, in case of group means (`type` is `3` or `4`) group mean
> centering for these predictors are conducted before doing imputations.
> Default is `FALSE`.

Using this option, it is possible to center predictor variables around the person mean instead of including the predictor variable "as is" (i.e., without centering). This only applies to variables coded as `3` or `4`. For predictors coded as `3`, this is not very important because the models with and without centering are identical.

However, when predictor variables are coded as `4` (i.e., with a random slope), then centering alters the meaning of the random effect so that the random slope no longer applies to the variable "as is" but to the within-person deviation of that variable.

---

In your example, you can include a simple random slope for `time` as follows:

```
library(mice)
ini <- mice(df, maxit=0)

# predictor matrix (following 'type')
pred <- ini$predictorMatrix
pred["score",] <- c(-2, 1, 2, 0)

# imputation method
meth <- c("", "", "", "2l.pan")

imp <- mice(df, method=meth, pred=pred, maxit=10, m=10)
```

In this example, coding `time` as `3` or `4` wouldn't make a lot of sense because the person means of `time` are identical for all persons. However, if you have time-varying covariates that you want to include as predictor variables in the imputation model, `3` and `4` can be useful.

The additional arguments like `intercept` and `groupcenter.slope` can be specified directly in the call to `mice()`, for example:

```
imp <- mice(df, ..., groupcenter.slope=TRUE)
```

---

### Regarding your Questions

So, to answer your questions as stated in the post:

1. Yes, `2l.pan` provides a multilevel (or rather two-level) imputation model. The intercept is included as both a fixed and a random effect by default (can be changed with `intercept=FALSE`) and need not be specified in the predictor matrix (this is in contrast to `2l.norm`).
2. Yes, you can specify random slopes with `2l.pan`. To do that, predictors with random slopes are coded as `2` or `4` in the predictor matrix. If coded
   as `2`, the random slope is included. If coded as `4`, the random slope is included as well as an additional fixed effect for the person means of that variable. If coded as `4`, the meaning of the random slope may be altered by making use of `groupcenter.slope=TRUE` (see above).

This article also includes some worked examples for how to work with `2l.pan` and other functions for mutlivel imputation: [[Link]](http://journals.sagepub.com/doi/full/10.1177/1094428117703686)

Comment: Brilliant answer @SimonG. Totally made my day. The previous poster's answer was good but I cannot fail to give you the accepted answer given how comprehensive and on-point it was.

Answer (score 6):

The `pan` library doesn't require an intercept term.

You can dig into the function using

```
library(pan)
?pan
```

That said `mice` uses a wrapper around pan called `mice.impute.2l.pan` with the `mice` library loaded you can look at the help for that function. It states: it has a parameters called `intercept` which is `[a] Logical [and] determin[es] whether the intercept is automatically added.` It is TRUE by default. This is defined as a random intercept by default. Found this out after browsing the R code for the mice wrapper:

`if (intercept) {
        x <- cbind(1, as.matrix(x))
        type <- c(2, type)
    }`

Where the `pan` function parameter `type` is a `Vector of length ncol(x) identifying random and class variables`. The intercept is added by default and defined as a random effect.

They do provide and example like you stated with a 1 for "x" in the prediction matrix for fixed effects.

It also states for `2l.norm`, `The random intercept is automatically added in mice.impute.2l.norm().`

It has a few examples with descriptions.
[The CRAN documentation for `pan` might help you.](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pan/pan.pdf)

Comment: Thanks @Matt L. So as far as you know there is no random-slopes imputation method?

Comment: Unusual is the passage in `mice.impute.2l.norm()` help that says `The currently implemented algorithm does not handle predictors that are specified as fixed effects (type=1). When using mice.impute.2l.norm(), the current advice is to specify all predictors as random effects (type=2).` So all the fixed effects in my model should be specified as random, and the traditional random effect, `id` is specified as a class variable. I must admit I do not get it, but thank you for pointing me in that direction.